# I have an issue with an invalid identifier configuration in API Platform

Tags: symfony, symfony4, api-platform.com

So basically I'm creating a simple API to return a random quote based on the language field instead of the ID field for a `Quote` entity. I'm using Symfony 4 with the api-platform and tried to create a custom `GetRandomQuote` action for `itemOperations` that requires a `:language` identifier.

I've already created a custom operation / action `GetRandomQuote`, created a custom data provider `QuoteItemDataProvider` and marked the language field in the Quote Entity as an `ApiProperty` of type identifier. Yet, whenever I try to make a call to the api endpoint with the language field I get an ""Not found, because of an invalid identifier configuration". What am I missing here?

The Quote entity field

```
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ApiProperty(identifier=true)
     * @ORM\Column(name="language", type="string", length=5, nullable=false)
     */
    private $language;
```

The custom data provider:

```
    /**
     * @param string      $resourceClass
     * @param string|null $operationName
     * @param array       $context
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function supports(string $resourceClass, string $operationName = null, array $context = []) : bool
    {
        return Quote::class === $resourceClass && 'random' === $operationName;
    }

    /**
     * @param string           $resourceClass
     * @param array|int|string $identifiers
     * @param string|null      $operationName
     * @param array            $context
     *
     * @return Quote|null
     */
    public function getItem(string $resourceClass,
                            $identifiers,
                            string $operationName = null,
                            array $context = []) : ?Quote
    {
        if ( 'randomn' === $operationName ) {
            $quotes = $this->quoteRepository->findBy([ 'language' => $identifiers['language'], 'approved' => true ]);
            return $quotes[ array_rand($quotes, 1) ];
        }

        return null;
    }
```

So, basically I want to receive a random quote based on a language field that exists inside the `Quote` entity. Right now, I'm just receiving an `Not found, because of an invalid identifier configuration`

I've read the API documentation but so far couldn't understand what I'm missing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: did you implement the Api Ressource with a Get method for item operation https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#enabling-and-disabling-operations ?